# Does AWS-Lambda concurrency affect the limits of other services i.e ses/sns

Tags: amazon-web-services, concurrency, aws-lambda, boto3, amazon-ses

I have SES "Maximum sending rate" of 25 email/sec can I send 50 emails using sendBulkTemplatedEmail action? At the same time, I am trying to find out a way to use Lambda service, again I have the issue if I call 100 lambdas concurrently and each is responsible for sending 50 bulk-emails, does it affect sending rate and will return error "max sending rate exceeded". your help means a lot.

Comment: Are you mean that you want to send 5000 emails at the same time?

Comment: I am using SES, which takes much time and sometimes gives timeout error while sending a templated email to thousands of users. So I studied lambda service, and i am trying to find a way to send emails asynchronously so, I could send thousands of emails in seconds. my questions is SES max send limit cause error or not when its limit is exceeded. @Lamanus

Comment: It will be limited. Your SES service is unique.

Comment: Its mean lambda is useless in this case, we cannot take advantage of its asynchronous feature. instead of lambda, I should use sendBulkTempaltedEmail action of SES.

Answer (score 1):

Each AWS service has its own limit https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/aws_service_limits.html

SES limits will not be affected by lambda concurrency limit which defaults to 1000 concurrent executions per account.

Comment: even if I run 100 or more lambda functions in loop and pass 100 emails to each lambda to send those emails using SES which has (25 email/sec) limit. It will work smoothly?